# Benefits/negatives of password-less authentication

Tags: authentication, websites

I am facing the following dilemma:

I have a client who has a very basic admin panel, he uses this once or twice a week and cannot do much, mainly update content and add products.

Currently, the admin panel requires you to enter your username and password. On most days, he forgets his password calls us up and we have to reset his password (Even though there is a reset password option).

This got me thinking, he uses his emails and he uses his Mobile Phone quite a lot. So, if I took the password method away and did the following:

- He enters his email/phone number
- He get's an email with a special code He enters that code and he can
  access the admin panel (for up to
  half a day e.g.)

I am thinking that this would solve a lot of problems, but what are the security implications for this? If we could get away from password, why hasn't this been done by some of the leading providers? I want to go ahead with this authentication, but if it's not secure then there is no point.

P.S. The emails will be sent over a secure network.

Comment: Maybe use something like Auth0? That way your client can use Google/Facebook for logging in

Comment: Email is *never* a secure service, even if over a supposedly secure network - even if you consider your local network secure, there is still the connection on the client's side, and the general internet in the middle. Only exception would be if it never left your own network.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere So in essence, what I am proposing is actually a bad idea?

Comment: @Phorce Not necessarily, but do not assume that just because your network is secure, emails sent via it are secure. The biggest problem I can see with this scheme is that the chance of the person losing (or having stolen) the cellphone/ laptop are quite high.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere No offence to the person, if he loses his phone / laptop then it's kinda their own fault. Also, the code does not last for a long period. Surely I can secure it by logging the IP address that they requested the token? For example, if they request it at their office then they can log in using that token.. If they go home, they have to request a new token? Because there's a different IP.. Make sense?

Comment: Just because it's their own fault does not mean that you shouldn't protect against it, or won't be blamed if it does happen and something goes wrong. IP-based auth might cause annoyance if using cellular internet, as the IP can change very frequently.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Very valid point. Can you suggest anyway of securing such a method? If I wanted to do it..

Comment: why ask for the authentication credential directly? I would think its better to ask for a user name and than send the authentication request to the stored endpoint for it.